# How to retrieve data from `window` object - React?

Tags: reactjs, state, window-object

I am super new to ReactJS. I am trying to assign third party script file to my Window obbject like below code in my componentDidmount method.

```
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "www.xxx.com/src/data.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        console.log(window);
```

from last console log, I get full window object with third party scripts's data. But next I tried to a set that data to my state like below in same component after above code.

```
           this.setState({
                dataBook: window.databook,
                dataTopic: window.datatopic
            })
```

but state assigned as undefined. I tried using Helmet and script-tag npm as well. I think I am not doing it right. How to retrieve data from window object? Thanks
Full component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            url:"https://example.com/src/customdata.js",
            dataBook: [],
            dataTopic: [],
            dataLesson: [],
            dataGloss: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = this.state.url;
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        console.log(window);

        this.setState({
                dataBook: window.databook,
                dataTopic: window.datatopic,
                dataLesson: window.datalesson,
                dataGloss: window.datagloss
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div>Book Titles</div>
                {
                    window.databook.map((item)=>{
                        console.log(item)
                    })
                }
                <hr/>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please show the entire component`s code

Comment: Can you please give more details about in what sequence you are appending the script tag in the body and setting the state ?

Comment: @SagiRika I posted full component.

Comment: @VishalSharma I posted full component.

Comment: Not sure why you are fetching the data using the script tag and then adding it into window as well as state. You should get the data using JS fetch and then set it into the state.

Right now I feel, the script src has not fetched the data and the statement to set the state got executed which causes the problem.

Comment: @VishalSharma Sorry I do not get the script src not fetched! on console log Full window object prints with third party scripts data. can you specify the JS fetch method ? link or something ?

Comment: You can follow https://javascript.info/fetch to get more information about fetch.

Comment: @VishalSharma Thank you!!

Comment: Let me please know if the advice has helped you.